# Im using windows 8 64 bits but all my .exe run at 32 bit

Tags: windows

why do my .exe run on 32bit while windows is on 64bit? is it possible to switch them to 64bits? thanks!
If i go to the task manager is have the .exe name followed with (32 bit).

Comment: If the exe is 32 bit, it will run as 32bit, Windows 64 bit os has a 32 bit subsystem for backwards compatibility for older exe's.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you're running a 64 bit OS, doesn't make all applications run in 64 bit.

So, you would need to find out if the application in question has a 64 bit version and install that instead.